# "Obsoleting Packages"の意味は？

Tags: linux, yum, rhel

`yum check-update`でパッケージの更新をチェックしていたのですが下記が表示されました。

`Obsoleting Packages`（[訳名称](http://lists.baseurl.org/pipermail/yum-devel/2010-March/006691.html)：`パッケージを不要にしています`）

上記の意味合いについて教えてほしいです。
・インストールされているパッケージがどこにも使用されていない
・インストールされているパッケージがアップデート(インストール)リストにない
・このパッケージを使用するべきではない警告

また、この表示にあるパッケージはアップデートがあり、
アップデートが可能ということなのでしょうか？

直訳すると「時代遅れなパッケージ」ということですが、
翻訳されている名称を見て余計に混乱しています。

もし不要、もしくは使うべきでないのであれば削除するべきでしょうか？
既に運用しているサーバーなので出来るだけアップデート以外したくないのですが、
そのまま放置、またはアップデートしても問題ないのでしょうか？

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) 廃止されるパッケージのことで他のパッケージが代わりになります。

例えば foo パッケージが bar に変更された場合、foo の更新パッケージは bar になり foo は廃止されるパッケージになります。

(2) この他に、依存パッケージが変更になった場合も Obsoltes Package に表示されます。

たとえば、foo パッケージが依存している hoge が 新バージョンでは不要になった場合、foo の Obsoletes に hoge が表示されます。

どちらの場合も `yum upgrade` を実行すると廃止されるパッケージは削除されます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。こちらは廃止パッケージリストだということで、アップデートリストの最下部に`Obsoleting Packages`の一覧は出てますが、代替のパッケージはアップデートリスト上部の中に含まれてるか、既に最新が入っていて、`Obsoleting Packages`に記載されているパッケージは削除するなりしても良いということでしょうか？

Comment: yum updeade fooとしますとfooが削除されbarが入ります。fooを消してbarを入れても同じかもしれませんがよくわかりません…

Comment: 上は間違いでyum upgrade fooでした。

Comment: なるほど、現時点では”廃止するよ”とメッセージが来てる段階で、まだ更新先は入っていない状態なのですね。納得しました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: Obsoletesは更新されるRPMにメタ情報として書かれており、yum はそれを表示してるだけです。なのでどういった状況なのか・・・というのはケースバイケースで色々有りそうな気がします。

Comment: 説明が片手落ちでしたので、編集しました。もしかすると @Myaku さんの状況は、回答の (2) の方かもしれません。

Comment: 今回、2つのパッケージが対象に上がっていたのですが、試験用のミラーサーバで1つずつアップデートをrpmで当てたところ1つは表示から消えたので(1)だったのかな？と感じました。もう1つの方は(2)なんだと思いますが手動で`yum remove`しました。試験していますが今のところ問題はなさそうです。フォローありがとうございます。