# mysql-devel => mariadb-devel のように、実際にインストールされるパッケージが変わる場合に、元のパッケージ名でインストール済みか判定したい

Tags: amazon-ec2, yum, amazon-linux

itamae で ec2 インスタンスのプロヴィジョニングを行おうとしていました。

mysql-devel のパッケージが、何度実行してもインストール済みとして扱われないので(毎回毎回 yum install しているような挙動を示した)、サーバー上で調べてみたところ mariadb-devel がインストールされている様子でした。

ここから、おそらく yum には、そのパッケージにおいて、 alias 的な仕組みがあるのではないかと考えています。

#### 質問

- mysql-devel をインストールしても mariadb-devel が実際にはインストールされているような、指定したパッケージとは別のパッケージがインストールされるような場合において、初めに指定したパッケージ名称を使って、そのパッケージがすでにインストールされているかを確認する方法/コマンドはありますか?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

パッケージの情報はメタデータで管理されており、他のパッケージを置き換える場合には「Obsoletes Package」として情報を持っています。

要望をあげている内容は自分でダミーの野良パッケージを作成、インストールなどで無理矢理できない事もないですが、
置き換えられる側は「廃止されたパッケージ」なので、新しいパッケージ名できちんと管理すべきかと思います。

関連
["Obsoleting Packages"の意味は？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/28423/3060)